# pdf-lib trigger field javascript

Tags: javascript, events, field, pdf-lib.js

I have a pdf that has a field with javascript that concatenates two other fields into it. When using pdf-lib and using setText for the two other fields, the field with javascript doesn't get triggered to update itself. How do I do that programmatically?

Additionally, I have a barcode that needs to be triggered to load from the values that I have loaded on my form. I am assuming that I would be able to trigger that event in the same manner.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to trigger those calculated fields and I will need to calculate them in my code and just set them. That is what you are saying, correct?

Comment: Is there a library that can be used in this particular fashion? Maybe pdf-lib is not the correct one for me to be using?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the example of Add A + B and show as C is a very simplistic example. Consider this, you add a BarCode to your pdf, and it is a combination of 100+ fields. Within Adobe, the custom javascript allows you to put all of this together and the barcode is generated from the value list when you set the field with event.value = combination of all fields plus the *EOD* tag. Filling in the pdf fillable fields, and then triggering the javascript allows you to not have to generate the barcode and then add the generated image since it is self-contained.